# angularjs - how to generate dynamic pages if my response is changing structure at runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat

normally, we can use ngRepeat="item in items" then use item.name to print out the name of the item. But what if the item has a dynamic structure which is only generated at run-time?

Say the item may have the following structure.

e.g.

```
data{
  field1: textfield;
  field2: integerfield;
  data:{
     field1:textfield;
     data:{
        field1:radiofield;
     }
     ...
  }
}
```

How can we print out all 'leaves' of this tree ?

Comment: Imho you should prepare your data in the controller before rendering them in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that preparing the data in the controller before passing to ng-repeat is the simplest solution. Here is a simple [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/peboho/2/edit?html,js,output) that pushes all of the properties of an object into a flat array and then prints the array to screen using ng-repeat.

Comment: Great recursive controller example. Thanks a lot. Only problem is that the "flattern function" loses the original tree structure.